# Override UITableViewCell initialized from xib file

Tags: ios

I want change some things (hidden a UITextView, change Font color) dinamically when initialize  my custom UITableViewCell (from xib file), but initWithStyle selector isn't called.

My code below:

GoalTableCell.h

```
@interface GoalTableCell : UITableViewCell

  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fixedText;

  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *editableText;

  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageCircle;

@end
```

GoalTableCell.m

```
@implementation GoalTableCell

- (void) setup
{
  self.editableText.hidden = TRUE;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
  if( self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier] ) {
    [self setup];
  }

  return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Try calling setup from awakeFromNib instead.

Answer (score 3):

When any instance is unarchived from a NIB file the 'initWithCoder:`method will be called because the archived properties are provided to the instance via the`decoder` parameter.

When instances are loaded from a NIB the `awakeFromNib` method is also called.

initWithCoder:`is called to create the instance.`awakeFromNib` is called after the instance has been fully unarchived (outlets are connected) from the NIB.

Comment: Thanks @Wain, initWithCoder really is called, but while it is invoked IBOutlets still wasnt initialized, all are nil